# How to save position in Ext.form.field.Picker after collapse() event?

Tags: extjs

After click on picker - it expands. After click on element of picker - list closes. And if I want click again position isn't save? How resolve it?

```
onValueSelected: function (sender, value) {
        this.setValue(value);
        this.collapse();
    },
```

Comment: ExtJS version? What kind of Picker? Just a straight Picker? No ComboBox/TagField?

Comment: ExtJS 4.2, combobox. Friend, how to save scrollbar status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try whether `combo.getPicker().getEl()` or `combo.getPicker().getView()` is available in your ExtJS version and has a `scroll` or `scrollable` property. If you find it, you can save the scroll position and restore it in a listener each, somehow similar to this one:

```
listeners:{
    collapse:function(cb) {
        cb.topPos = cb.getPicker().getScrollable().getPosition().y;
    },
    expand:function(cb) {
        cb.getPicker().getScrollable().scrollTo(0,cb.topPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. but...Scroll and scrollable properties is not available for for Picker.
How to save scrollbar position and after setValue event - call saved scrollbar pos?

Comment: Something like this:

 onValueSelected: function (sender, value) {
        var pos = scrollTop;
        this.setValue(value);
        this.collapse();
        this.scrollTop = pos;
    },